# How do you get down the hill on the campaign level, SOG?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

In Call of Duty: Black Ops, on the mission SOG (Vietnam), you come to a point where your orders are to push back the NVA down the hill. I've spent a lot of time slowly pushing down the hill but the enemies keep coming and on Veteran difficulty at some point I always end up dying. My squad mates pretty much stop at the first level down the hill providing no help.

I'm sure a portion of it is skill, but there must be something I'm missing to trigger my squad mates to continue on down and move the level forward and stop the enemy from spawning. Any ideas?

Comment: This part was incredibly annoying, I couldn't figure it out either, I never did figure out the barrels, but somehow managed to reach a checkpoint where half of the team moved on, but 2 guys including the one the game told me to follow, just stayed back there doing nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of them will come at you regularly and some of them will not reveal themselves until you have reached a certain spot, so keep moving, but take it slowly.

Going kamikaze on veteran means certain death.

As soon as you clear all positions, they stop spawning.

You can roll barrels burning (just knife them by pressing "use" key) and use the machine gun at the side to make things easier.

Comment: I think the barrels may be what I'm looking for here. I know they mention something about napalm in barrels when you're getting to the hill, but which ones? I've seen no indication or prompt that you can kick the barrels at the very top.

Comment: They are the ones at the lower level of the descending (first) part. Must be three of them.

Comment: It's the ones that are kind of dark blue with yellow stripes running across them.  I was stuck on this bit for ages until someone told me about the barrels.  Once you knock them all down, your squad pushes down the hill themselves.

Comment: Remember, Woods will kick 2 of the barrels for you. You only actually have to kick one.

Answer (score 9):

You do kick the barrels.  Get close enough and an action prompt appears allowing you to pierce the barrels and kick them.  They then explode keeping the enemy at bay.  You need to do this with the 3 barrels before you will be able to move on.

Comment: Actually, Woods will kick a couple of them for you. When I played this on veteran I only had to kick the one on the far right.

Answer (score 2):

Barrels are the key. Ignore everything else. Go up to them and they will give you a prompt, or Woods will activate them. The rest of the squad then moves forward.